# How to find all elements in array included by range efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a big array of date elements, array is already sorted.

`[2020.12.31, 2020.12.31, 2021.01.03, 2021.01.04, 2021.01.04, 2021.02.16, 2021.06.16]` etc.

And there is some range: `[2021.01.03, 2021.05.15]`

I need to find all elements which are included by this range: `[2021.01.03, 2021.01.04, 2021.01.04, 2021.02.16]`

I coded one solution, but it is not efficient for big array. I think this can be solved by using binary search, but I don't have idea how to.

My code:

```js
       let i = 0,
        j = eventsId.length - 1,
        startIndex,
        endIndex
      while (!startIndex && !endIndex && i < j) {
        if (!startIndex) {
          if (
            events[eventsId[i]].startDate >= interval.start
          )
            startIndex = i
          else i++
        }
        if (!endIndex) {
          if (events[eventsId[j]].startDate <= interval.end)
            endIndex = j
          else j--
        }
      }
      if (startIndex && endIndex) {
        return eventsId.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1)
      }
```

Comment: You might improve it if you don't create `new Date`s every time, since your dates have year-month-day in a normalized format, string comparison should work just as well

Comment: also you might want to break the while once your endIndex is set

Comment: @OvidiuDolha thanks, I will remove ```new Date```. But also I need move from O(n) to O(log n) I think

Comment: you could implement some sort of binary search. Issue you have is not having an exact match and possibility there are multiple matches.  Personally I would have implemented it the way you have.

Comment: Why are you worried about the asymptotic time complexity of this?  Those are formatted dates.  How big do you think the array of them will ever grow?

Answer (score 1):

You could treat the date strings as string and compare directly with the range values without converting to `Date` objects.

```js
const
    data = ['2020.12.31', '2020.12.31', '2021.01.03', '2021.01.04', '2021.01.04', '2021.02.16', '2021.06.16'],
    range = ['2021.01.03', '2021.05.15'],
    result = data.filter(d => d >= range[0] && d <= range[1]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This one is O(n). I think there can be more efficient way to solve this.

Comment: do you have the exact date of the wanted range in the array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're worrying about an unnecessary optimization.  Here is a test that takes slightly over one million ordered dates, and then finds the matches in a given range.  We time the call for the small range you supplied and for one with 300,000+ results, using a simple `.filter`-based function.

On my mid-range laptop the two calls take between 18ms and 43ms.  If I reduce it to the 8000 or so far this century, they're under 1ms.

Do you really need to speed this up?  Are you doing it in a tight loop?

```js
const rng = (lo, hi) => [...new Array(hi - lo + 1)] .map ((_, i) => i + lo)

// not exact dates, but fine for demo
const ds = rng(1, 3000)
  .flatMap (y => 
    rng(1, 12) .flatMap (m => rng(1, 30) .map (
      d => `${String(y).padStart(4, '0')}.${String(m).padStart(2, '0')}.${String(d).padStart(2, '0')}`)
    )
  )

const findMatches = (ds) => (start, stop) =>
  ds.filter (d => d >= start && d <= stop)

console .log ('Total dates:', ds .length)
console .time ('calc time')
console .log ('found in [2021.01.03 - 2021.05.15]:', findMatches(ds)('2021.01.03', '2021.05.15') .length)
console .timeEnd ('calc time')

console .time ('calc time 2')
console .log ('found in [1166.01.03 - 2021.05.15]:', findMatches(ds)('1166.01.03', '2021.05.15') .length)
console .timeEnd ('calc time 2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code for an O(lg N) solution

```
first = binarysearch(lower)
last = binarysearch(high+1)

solution = array (first ... last)
```

`binarysearch` should return the first element where every element before is lower than the parameter